# How to find the duplicate rows in the table using sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have tried this query to get the duplicate records.but I am getting this error.

```
select * from Codes
where id = 35712 and isactive = 1
group by line_num
having count(*) > 1
```

I am getting this error.

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'Codes.code_id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

here code_id is the primary key for this table.

can anybody help me out how to get the code_id which have duplicates in this table.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server 2005 and later you can use aggregate window functions:

```
;WITH counted AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    Cnt = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY line_num)
  FROM Codes
  WHERE id = 35712
    AND isactive = 1
)
SELECT *
FROM counted
WHERE Cnt > 1
```

References:

- [Aggregate Functions (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx)
- [OVER Clause (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)
- [WITH common_table_expression (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

```
select count(line_num), 
       line_num 
from   codes 
where  id = 35712 
       and isactive = 1 
group  by line_num 
having count(line_num) > 1
```

Answer (score 2):

It search for duplicated values in line_num column, where code_id is primary key of codes table. I don't know exact table definition so this is a bit of guessing.

```
select c.code_id, c.line_num, t.qt from codes c
join (
    select line_num, count(*) as qt
    from codes
    where id = 35712 and isActive = 1
    group by line_num
    having count(*) > 1
) as t on t.line_num = c.line_num
```

First columns returns all code_ids that have duplicated value in line_num (second column), qt - quantity.

Answer (score 1):

```
select code_id, line_num, count(*) from Codes 
where id = 35712 and isactive = 1 
group by code_id, line_num
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: if I do group by with primary key I am not getting any records out.

Comment: If code_id is primary key then pair: code_id, line_num isn't always unique?

Comment: if id is your primary key, there cannot be more than one row with id 35712.

Comment: here id can be more then one record, but ba_code_id should be primary key.

Comment: how about you show us your table definition? as is now you're just randomly giving us extra info on columns...